# Is NULL value on intval() = 0?

Tags: php

Is NULL value on intval() = 0 ?

```
$value = NULL
$value2 = intval($value) // will be 0?
```

Is that correct, please let me know ?

Answer (score 9):

Yes you can easy test that like this:

```
$value = NULL;
echo $value2 = intval($value) ;
```

Output:

```
0
```

Since:

The return value is the integer value of $value on success! And on failure 0.

Comment: You could simply use `var_dump(intval(NULL));` as well ;)